# Redimensionar imagen que viene por POST en PHP

Tags: php, post

Como puedo redimensionar una imagen que me viene por POST de un formulario??

```
$rutaFichero = '/img/' . basename($_FILES['imagenNoticia']['name']);

if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['imagenNoticia']['tmp_name'], $rutaFichero))
        {
            $imagenOriginal = imagecreatefromjpeg($rutaFichero);
            $maxAncho = 500;
            $maxAlto = 500;
            list($ancho, $alto) = getimagesize($rutaFichero);
            $xRatio = $maxAncho / $ancho;
            $yRatio = $maxAlto / $alto;

            if(($ancho <= $maxAncho) && ($alto <= $maxAlto))
            {
                $anchoFinal = $ancho;
                $altoFinal = $alto;
            }
            else if(($xRatio * $alto) < $maxAlto)
            {
                $altoFinal = ceil($xRatio * $alto);
                $anchoFinal = $maxAncho;
            }
            else
            {
                $anchoFinal = ceil($yRatio * $ancho);
                $altoFinal = $maxAlto;
            }

            //$rsr_org = imagecreatefromjpeg("image.jpg");
            //$tmp = imagescale($imagenOriginal, $anchoFinal, $altoFinal,  IMG_BICUBIC_FIXED);
            //imagejpeg($tmp, basename($_FILES['imagenNoticia']['name']);

            $tmp = imagecreatetruecolor($anchoFinal, $altoFinal);
            $resultado = imagecopyresampled($tmp, $imagenOriginal, 0, 0, 0, 0, $anchoFinal, $altoFinal, $ancho, $alto);
            imagedestroy($imagenOriginal);
        }
```

He utilizado este codigo, pero no me redimensiona la imagen. Alguna posible solucion?, O alguna clase que funcione con versiones de php anteriores a la 5.3? Gracias

Comment: El problema es que la version de php de mi servidor es la 5.3 y el namespace y el use, no funcionan, pero gracias de todas formas

Comment: Has podido intentar aplicar lo que he comentado en mi respuesta?

Comment: Sabeis si hay alguna clase para redimensionar que funcione con versiones de php anteriores a la 5.3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He encontrado esto que te puede ayudar (Creo que el problema que tienes está en el ratio):

```
$fn = $_FILES['imagenNoticia']['name'];
$size = getimagesize($fn);
$ratio = $size[0]/$size[1]; // width/height
if( $ratio > 1) {
    $width = 500;
    $height = 500/$ratio;
}
else {
    $width = 500*$ratio;
    $height = 500;
}
$src = imagecreatefromstring(file_get_contents($fn));
$dst = imagecreatetruecolor($width,$height);
imagecopyresampled($dst,$src,0,0,0,0,$width,$height,$size[0],$size[1]);
imagedestroy($src);
imagepng($dst,$target_filename_here); // adjust format as needed
imagedestroy($dst);
```

Comment: Me da error con las 4 ultimas funciones: "supplied argument is not a valid Image resource". Pero sigo intentado solucionarlo con tu codigo, Gracias!

Comment: Modifica `target_filename_here` por el nombre de la imagen

Comment: Si, eso ya lo habia cambiado, creo que ya se cual es el problema, lo estaba poniendo todo dentro de: "if (move_uploaded_file(", lo voy a sacr fuera y creo que deberia funcionar con tu codigo

Comment: Sigue sin funcionar, seguire probando haber si lo consigo y puedo poner aqui la solución

Comment: Mirando mejor tu código creo que lo único que te falta es lo de `imagepng($dst,$target_filename_here);` pon alerts antes y después y comprueba que no peta.

Comment: Con el codigo que me has pasado ha funcionado, tenia un error en el tamaño de la imagen que pesaba 7mb y el imagepng() daba error. Gracias

Answer (score 0):

Te dejo una función que uso yo, por si te sirve

```
function redimensionarJPEG ($origen, $destino, $ancho_max, $alto_max, $fijar) {

$info_imagen= getimagesize($origen);
$ancho=$info_imagen[0];
$alto=$info_imagen[1];
if ($ancho>=$alto)
{
    $nuevo_alto= round($alto * $ancho_max / $ancho,0);
    $nuevo_ancho=$ancho_max;
}
else
{
    $nuevo_ancho= round($ancho * $alto_max / $alto,0);
    $nuevo_alto=$alto_max;
}
switch ($fijar)
{
    case "ancho":
        $nuevo_alto= round($alto * $ancho_max / $ancho,0);
        $nuevo_ancho=$ancho_max;
        break;
    case "alto":
        $nuevo_ancho= round($ancho * $alto_max / $alto,0);
        $nuevo_alto=$alto_max;
        break;
    default:
        $nuevo_ancho=$nuevo_ancho;
        $nuevo_alto=$nuevo_alto;
        break;
}
$imagen_nueva= imagecreatetruecolor($nuevo_ancho,$nuevo_alto);
$imagen_vieja= imagecreatefromjpeg($origen);
imagecopyresampled($imagen_nueva, $imagen_vieja, 0, 0, 0, 0,$nuevo_ancho, $nuevo_alto, $ancho, $alto);
imagejpeg($imagen_nueva,$destino);
imagedestroy($imagen_nueva);
imagedestroy($imagen_vieja);
}
```