# Como hago para subir una foto por ftp con php y esta cree varios archivos en diferentes tamaños?

Tags: php, html, web, imagen, ftp

para detallar lo que necesito es subir una imagen con php, eso ya lo tengo resuelto, lo que necesito que esta se guarde en diferentes tamaños. Por ejemplo subir una foto de perfil en 1000px x 1000px y que también cree una copia pero en 100x100 para usarla como icono por ejemplo.

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Intentaste algo?

Comment: laravel + intervention : https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/144666/81450

Comment: php + gd : https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/14001/81450

Comment: otra mas : https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/94294/81450

Comment: hay mas ejemplos, elige uno y dale un voto =) https://es.stackoverflow.com/search?q=imagecopyresampled